# I'm having very negative thoughts, can you help me?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm 27 years old and I recently started vocational studies for app development. The first year is mostly about introduction to c# programming and also a light introduction to html and javascript. I have never studied anything related to coding before.

I know how to make pixel art , music and sounds, but coding is just so difficult for me. My objective in life right now is to make a very simple game and I feel so frustrated because I can't achieve anything. I have even tried things like stencyl or construct 2 but even that kind of software I can't understand it enough to make a very simple game.

I'm breaking all the rules here, but, can you help me? I read about people that are like 2 months into coding and are already making games. Am I too dumb? Should I just quit altogether?

Comment: as you said, indeed you broke the rules here and won't get any answer. This site is structured to ask questions about game development but not somethink like how to get started. you can visit [our chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development) to get some hint on how to get started depending on your needs. hmm I noticed that you need 20 rep to access the chat. Maybe the best thing I can point you to is to ask in some forum, explaining your goal and getting pointed to the best path to follow

Comment: Consider RPGMaker it's super easy to get started with, and there is a ton of very easy learning material and full games that you can learn off of.

Comment: You are not dumb.  Making a game is hard.  It will take time to learn, that is normal.  Learning how to code a cohesive game in 2 months? that is crazy talk.

Comment: Everyone learns at a different pace, you just need to keep on trying until you get it right. Also, programming a videogame without previous coding experience is like running before learning to walk, I suggest you start with simple coding lessons (there are plenty of free online academies and even youtube tutorials). Once you have a clear understanding you can move on to simple games such as pong or tetris. After that you'll be able to move on to more complex projects. Remember, videogames require practice, patience and time, so just keep on practicing, you'll be amazed by the results.